# Как сделать проверку чисел в двух массивах?

Tags: c++

Суть программы угадать число, которое загадал компьютер, и в процессе отгадывания должно печататься, сколько чисел уже угадали и на тех ли они позициях. Но почему то работает через раз.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (playerNum[i] != playerNum[(i + 1) % 3])
            if (compNum[i] == playerNum[j])
                ++guessed;
    }


    if (compNum[i] == playerNum[i])
        inItsPlace++;
}
cout << "Угадано: " << guessed << ". На своих местах: " << inItsPlace << '\n';
```

Числа трехзначные, в массиве из трех элементов. Как сделать, чтобы не было повторений(например надо отгадать число 793, при вводе 707 почему то пишет, что угадано 0, хотя должно 1)

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (compNum[i] == playerNum[i]) {
        inItsPlace++;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (compNum[i] == playerNum[j]) {
            ++guessed;
            playerNum[j] = -1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
cout << "Угадано: " << guessed << ". На своих местах: " << inItsPlace << '\n';
```